# Plotly v5.3.1 not working in Jupyterlab 3.1.18 (desktop version)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter-lab, qgrid

```
!jupyter labextension list
```

the extensions:

```
JupyterLab v3.1.18
C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\share\jupyter\labextensions
    jupyterlab-plotly v5.3.1 enabled ok
    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.1 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
```

The *jupyterlab-plotly v5.3.1* is enabled, and I have installed the *node.js* as well.

It still can show the plotly picture, did I miss something?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You should not install node.js for recent plotly versions. You must have used outdated instructions

Comment: Have you looked through the Plotly documentation for configuring JupyterLab [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support)?

Comment: just upgraded from 3.0.4 to 3.2.0 and it works no issues.  have not installed node.js

Comment: @DerekO Yes, I have tried. Since my Jupyterlab is 3.x which is new. I don't have to get too many extensions.

Comment: @RobRaymond I just installed 3.1.18 last night(2021-10-14). I didn't see 3.2.0.

Comment: since https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.0.0 things are very simple. no messing with extensions

Comment: I am using plotly 5.3.1, still not working............. @RobRaymond